# MaxOpenPreparedStatements limit reached

Tags: spring, hibernate, apache-commons-dbcp

While starting the application once the scheduler starts running , I get the following error

**Caused by:** `java.sql.SQLException: MaxOpenPreparedStatements limit reached`

Below is the properties

```
    <entry key="jdbc.preparedStatementCacheSize" value="500" />
    <entry key="jdbc.initialSize" value="5" />
    <entry key="jdbc.maxActive" value="100" />
    <entry key="jdbc.maxIdle" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />
    <entry key="jdbc.minIdle" value="0" />
    <entry key="jdbc.validationQuery" value="select database()" />
    <entry key="jdbc.maxWait" value="16000"/>
```

**The bean datasource**

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>    
  <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true" />
  <property name="maxOpenPreparedStatements" alue="${jdbc.preparedStatementCacheSize}"/>     
  <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />  
  <property name="maxActive" value="${jdbc.maxActive}" />
  <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.maxIdle}" />
  <property name="minIdle" value="${jdbc.minIdle}" />
  <property name="validationQuery" value="${jdbc.validationQuery}" />
</bean>
```

Instead of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` if I use
`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` then I wont get this   exception.

I am using **Spring 2.5.** Please help me in resolving this exception.

Comment: what is your scheduler doing? code?

Comment: Try increasing preparedStatementCacheSize size

Comment: I have increased the  preparedStatementCacheSize to 750 , but still i am getting the same exception

Comment: Assuming that the `jdbc.*` properties are set on hibernate remove them as those are useless due to the fact you are configuring a datasource. If your resources don't get cleaned up properly I suspect wrong or absent tx management. Post some additional configuration and code that is doing data access.

Comment: Any disadvantages if I put "poolPreparedStatements" value="false"